# GWT Locale does work in address bar, does not work in meta

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I have a gwt portlet with (for now) localization in English (default) and Dutch.

If I put ?locale=nl& in the address bar, I get nice Dutch texts. However, if I put `<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=nl" >` in the head of my html file, without any reference to locale in the address bar, I get the English texts. When I look into the rendered html source, I can see the `<meta>` tag. According to the documentation it should give Dutch texts.

Does anybody have a suggestion about where I should look to fix this?

Comment: If you compile in `-style PRETTY` and look at the generated `moduleName.nocache.js`, do you see a call to `__gwt_getMetaProperty("locale")`?

Answer (score 1):

You could set fallback property value for locale in your module's `.gwt.xml` which will be used as default

```
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="nl" />
```

Then if you need to change localization (e.g. to English) set correct `locale` URL parameter when loading portlet.

Also remember to set these properties in you module's `.gwt.xml`

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="nl" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I put my meta tag at the end of my  part, so it was after the  tag. I assumed the head was loaded completely before anything was done. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include your meta tag in the head but BEFORE the js script containing you GWT module code is called.